# Center all marker and poly line google maps plugin flutter fit to screen

Tags: google-maps, flutter

I want to put all markers in the center of maps with fit zoom to device size
 below is the code what I have done.
 I'm using google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.18 to develop a basic 'multiple markers on 
 a google map' type Flutter screen

1. Set it static initially In the add markers() function,
2. I Will just create Map of the marker and convert it to set and then I just pass it to Google map widget

   ```
   import 'dart:async';
       import 'dart:math';
       import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
       import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
       import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
       import 'package:flutter_app/utils/AppConstants.dart';
       import 'package:flutter_app/utils/AppDimens.dart';
       import 'package:flutter_app/utils/CommonColors.dart';
       import 'package:flutter_app/utils/CommonUtils.dart';
       import 'package:flutter_app/utils/networ_util.dart';

       import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
       import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
       import 'package:location/location.dart';
       import 'package:screen/screen.dart';

       class BusTrackingMap extends StatefulWidget {
         static String tag = "bus-tracking-page";

         @override
         State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
           // TODO: implement createState
           return _BusTrackingMapState();
         }
       }

       class _BusTrackingMapState extends State<BusTrackingMap>
           with TickerProviderStateMixin {
         static String homeMarkerId = "101";
         static String schoolMarkerId = "102";
         static String driverMarkerId = "103";
         static String polyLineId = "104";
         String apiKey = "";
         bool isFirstTimeCall = false, myLocationEnabled = true;
         Timer timer;

         /*map varibles*/
         static LatLng schoolLatLong = new LatLng(23.027115, 72.552368);
         static LatLng homeLatLong = new LatLng(23.023705, 72.538546);
         static LatLng driverLatLong = new LatLng(23.024311, 72.548505);
         Set<Marker> markerSet = new Set();
         List<Marker> markerList = new List();
         Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};
         Marker schoolMarker = new Marker(
             markerId: new MarkerId(schoolMarkerId),
             position: schoolLatLong,
             infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: "Parents Location", snippet: ""),
             icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset("images/ic_school.png"));
         Marker homeMarker = new Marker(
             markerId: new MarkerId(homeMarkerId),
             position: homeLatLong,
             infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: "School Location", snippet: ""),
             icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset("images/ic_hhome.png"));
         Marker driverMarker = new Marker(
             markerId: new MarkerId(driverMarkerId),
             position: driverLatLong,
             infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: "Driver Location", snippet: ""),
             icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset("images/ic_bus.png"));

         final Set<Polyline> polylineSet = new Set();
         Polyline polyline;
         List<LatLng> _latLongList = new List();

         // LatLng driverLatLong=new LatLng(23.028712, 72.570227);

         Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
         GoogleMapController _mapController;

         static CameraPosition _initialCamera = CameraPosition(
           target: driverLatLong,
           zoom: 14,
         );

         /*location update varible*/

         BuildContext mContext;
         CameraPosition _currentCameraPosition;
         StreamSubscription<LocationData> _locationSubscription;
         Location _locationService = new Location();
         bool _permission = false;
         String error;
         LocationData _startLocation;
         LocationData _currentLocation;

         /*widget varibles*/
         GoogleMap googleMap;
         Scaffold scaffold;
         BitmapDescriptor icon;
         AnimationController rotationController;

         @override
         void initState() {
           // TODO: implement initState
           super.initState();
           rotationController = AnimationController(
               duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), vsync: this);

           initPlatformState();
           requestPermission();
           addMarker();
           addMarkerAndPolyLine();
           refreshLocationDelay();
           // apiCallEveryInterval();
          }

         keepPhoneWake() async {
           double brightness = await Screen.brightness;
           Screen.setBrightness(0.5);
           bool isKeptOn = await Screen.isKeptOn;
           Screen.keepOn(true);
         }

         apiCallEveryInterval() {
           const oneSecond = const Duration(seconds: 20);
           timer = new Timer.periodic(oneSecond, (Timer t) => fetchDriverLocation());
           BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
                   ImageConfiguration(size: Size(48, 48)), "images/ic_hhome.png")
               .then((onValue) {
             icon = onValue;
           });
         }

         refreshLocationDelay() {
           rotationController.forward(from: 0.0);
           var _duration = new Duration(seconds: 1);
           return new Timer(_duration, refreshLocation);
         }

         void addMarker() {
           markers[schoolMarker.markerId] = schoolMarker;
           markers[homeMarker.markerId] = homeMarker;
           markers[driverMarker.markerId] = driverMarker;
           markerSet = Set<Marker>.of(markers.values);
         }

         void addMarkerAndPolyLine() {
           String encode =
               "m{siCmn{{LmAG?b@?bCBRb@p@hBdCfCfDnAtA|BvAxF|DlDdCb@T^Z`Ax@XV^r@fAnB|BbE|@dAnZiX`GiFzAsA|AkAfBqAtBeBxC}Bn@g@b@SVCd@@d@J\Nr@^pAx@j@f@vBpBlCpCtAbB^^d@Z^L^Bd@CJAZvDPIDEl@y@N[t@_CdA_DbAyDt@{AP[t@y@jCaCpCwBdAm@`@QfC_@jB[jOsBlEKlKIrA@l@dAx@fB`Ao@LI\En@GN@JA~@YhA_@ZSPOFIjE^nBLrBXbKlBfQfEjAb@`Af@~B`BtIxH~D|EtFjHnBoBjFaFhBiBTYZo@J[";
           getRoutes();
           NetworkUtil networkUtil = new NetworkUtil();
           _latLongList = networkUtil.decodePolyline(encode);
           polyline = new Polyline(
               polylineId: PolylineId(polyLineId),
               points: _latLongList,
               color: CommonColors.primaryColor,
               width: 10,
               visible: true);
           polylineSet.add(polyline);
         }

         void getRoutes(){
           if (!isFirstTimeCall) {
             NetworkUtil networkUtil = new NetworkUtil();
             String url = "origin=" +
                 schoolLatLong.latitude.toString() +
                 "," +
                 schoolLatLong.longitude.toString() +
                 "&destination=" +
                 homeLatLong.latitude.toString() +
                 "," +
                 homeLatLong.longitude.toString() +
                 "&key=" +
                 apiKey;
             networkUtil.get(url).then((latLongList) {
               _latLongList = latLongList;
             });
             isFirstTimeCall = true;
             print("Locaton Updated");
           }

         }
         @override
         Widget build(BuildContext context) {
           buildView();
           return scaffold;
         }

         void buildView() {
           final toolbar = new Row(
             crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
             children: <Widget>[
               InkWell(
                   onTap: () {
                     Navigator.pop(context);
                   },
                   child: Container(
                     alignment: Alignment.center,
                     height: 24,
                     width: 24,
                     margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, right: 0),
                     padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                     child: Icon(
                       Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                       color: CommonColors.primaryColor,
                     ),
                   )),
               Container(
                 padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 5),
                 alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                 child: Material(
                   color: Colors.transparent,
                   child: Text(AppConstants.track_bus,
                       style: TextStyle(
                           fontFamily: AppConstants.FONT_FAMILY,
                           fontSize: AppDimens.appBarTitleSize,
                           fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                           color: CommonColors.primaryColor)),
                 ),
               )
             ],
           );

           googleMap = GoogleMap(
             rotateGesturesEnabled: true,
             scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
             gestureRecognizers: Set()
               ..add(Factory<PanGestureRecognizer>(() => PanGestureRecognizer()))
               ..add(Factory<ScaleGestureRecognizer>(() => ScaleGestureRecognizer()))
               ..add(Factory<TapGestureRecognizer>(() => TapGestureRecognizer()))
               ..add(Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
                   () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer())),
             mapType: MapType.normal,
             myLocationEnabled: myLocationEnabled,
             myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
             zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
             markers: markerSet,
             polylines: polylineSet,
             minMaxZoomPreference: MinMaxZoomPreference.unbounded,
             initialCameraPosition: _initialCamera,
             onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController googleMapController){
                _mapController=googleMapController;
                _controller.complete(googleMapController);

             },
           );
           final mapView = Container(
             height: double.infinity,
             width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
             child: googleMap,
           );

           scaffold = Scaffold(
             appBar: AppBar(
               title: toolbar,
               backgroundColor: CommonColors.appBarColor,
               automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
             ),
             body: Builder(
               builder: (BuildContext context) {
                 mContext = context;
                 return mapView;
               },
             ),
             floatingActionButton: new Align(
                 alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                 child: new FloatingActionButton(
                     child: new Center(
                       child: RotationTransition(
                         turns:
                             Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(rotationController),
                         child: Icon(
                           Icons.refresh,
                           color: Colors.white,
                         ),
                       ),
                     ),
                     onPressed: () {
                       refreshLocation();
                     })),
           );
         }

         /*update location and map*/
         initPlatformState() async {
           await _locationService.changeSettings(
               accuracy: LocationAccuracy.HIGH, interval: 1000);

           LocationData location;
           // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
           try {
             bool serviceStatus = await _locationService.serviceEnabled();
             // print("Service status: $serviceStatus");
             if (serviceStatus) {
               _permission = await _locationService.requestPermission();
               //  print("Permission: $_permission");
               if (_permission) {
                 location = await _locationService.getLocation();

                 _locationSubscription = _locationService
                     .onLocationChanged()
                     .listen((LocationData result) async {
                   _currentCameraPosition = CameraPosition(
                       target: LatLng(result.latitude, result.longitude), zoom: 14);
                   final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
                   controller.animateCamera(
                       CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(_currentCameraPosition));

                   if (mounted) {
                     setState(() {
                       _currentLocation = result;
                       if (_currentCameraPosition != null)
                         _initialCamera = _currentCameraPosition;
                     });
                   }
                 });
               }
             } else {
               bool serviceStatusResult = await _locationService.requestService();
               //  print("Service status activated after request: $serviceStatusResult");
               if (serviceStatusResult) {
                 initPlatformState();
               }
             }
           } catch (e) {
             //  print(e);
             if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED') {
               error = e.message;
             } else if (e.code == 'SERVICE_STATUS_ERROR') {
               error = e.message;
             }
             location = null;
           }

           setState(() {
             _startLocation = location;
           });
         }

         dynamic refreshLocation() async {
           if (_locationSubscription != null) {
             _locationSubscription.cancel();
             await _locationService.changeSettings(
                 accuracy: LocationAccuracy.BALANCED, interval: 1000);
             _locationSubscription =
                 _locationService.onLocationChanged().listen((LocationData result) {
               print("SchoolEasy  Location" + result.longitude.toString());
               Scaffold.of(mContext).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                 backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                 content: new Text('Location Updated' + result.longitude.toString()),
               ));
               homeMarker = new Marker(
                 markerId: new MarkerId(homeMarkerId),
                 position: LatLng(result.latitude, result.longitude),
                 icon: icon,
                 infoWindow:
                     InfoWindow(title: "ParentLocation Location", snippet: "snippets"),
               );

               if (mounted) {
                 setState(() {
                   _currentLocation = result;
                   //  driverLatLong = new LatLng(result.latitude, result.longitude);
                   markers[homeMarker.markerId] = homeMarker;
                   markerSet = Set<Marker>.of(markers.values);
                   myLocationEnabled = false;
                   rotationController.stop(canceled: true);
                   if (_currentCameraPosition != null)
                     _initialCamera = _currentCameraPosition;
                 });
               }
             });
           } else {
             refreshLocationDelay();
           }
         }

         /*location permission handling */

       /*request permission if not allowed*/

         Future requestPermission() async {
           //  print("permission requested");
           Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus> permissions =
               await PermissionHandler()
                   .requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.location]);
         }

         /*check location service status*/

         /*Future<int> checkingServiceStatus() async {
           ServiceStatus serviceStatus =
               await PermissionHandler().checkServiceStatus(PermissionGroup.location);
           return serviceStatus.value;
         }

         Future<bool> requestRationalPermission() async {
           bool isShown = await PermissionHandler()
               .shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(PermissionGroup.location);
           return isShown;
         }*/

         Future<int> checkPermission() async {
           PermissionStatus permission = await PermissionHandler()
               .checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.location);
           return permission.value;
         }

         dynamic fetchDriverLocation() {
           //  print("location fetching");
         }

         @override
         void dispose() {
           super.dispose();
           if (timer != null) {
             timer.cancel();
           }
         }
   ```

   }

Comment: You need to put some code so that we can see what are you doing and which mistakes you make.

Comment: hi harunB10 I have added the code please tell me the possible solution of it thanks in advance

Answer (score 25):

This works fine for me. Have dart:math also imported for max, min functions.

```
 import 'dart:math';

 LatLngBounds getBounds(List<Marker> markers) {
    var lngs = markers.map<double>((m) => m.position.longitude).toList();
    var lats = markers.map<double>((m) => m.position.latitude).toList();

    double topMost = lngs.reduce(max);
    double leftMost = lats.reduce(min);
    double rightMost = lats.reduce(max);
    double bottomMost = lngs.reduce(min);

    LatLngBounds bounds = LatLngBounds(
      northeast: LatLng(rightMost, topMost),
      southwest: LatLng(leftMost, bottomMost),
    );

    return bounds;
}
```